# Verificar se o $_GET existe dentro da view

Tags: php, get, if

Galera é o seguinte, eu tenho um arquivo html padrão, que contém :

```
<header data-color="<?php echo $client->client_color; ?>"> 
<h1>
    <?php if($client->client_image != ''): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $client->client_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $client->name; ?>"/>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo lang('client_title'); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

...

Porém eu fiz uma função na controller, para o cliente ter a opção de passar a imagem e a cor por parâmetro na url :

```
private function SetImageAndColor($client_id) {
    if(isset($_GET['color']) AND isset($_GET['image'])) {
        $dados['client'] [$client_id] ['image'] = $this->input->get('image');
        $dados['client'] [$client_id] ['color'] = $this->input->get('color');
        $this->session->set_userdata('client', $dados);
    }
}
```

Como eu faço a verificação se o `$_GET` existir, ele coloca a imagem e a cor selecionada pelo cliente, se não, ela coloca a padrão?

Comment: Aqui você usa `$client->client_color` e aqui você usa `$dados['client'] [$client_id] ['image']`, ou seja, você está usando ou algum framework e não sabemos qual é, ou o correto deveria ser `$client->color;`. Suponho que não seja problema com o GET. Que framework é este? Outra coisa a cor está indo para o atributo `data-color`, este atributo não faz nada a não ser que seja usado por uma biblioteca JavaScript. Você visualizou o código fonte, de repente a cor está no atributo `data-color`, mas a biblioteca javascript é que está com problema.

Comment: Um simples `if` e `else`??

Comment: Exato, quero saber como monto o if e else dentro da estrutura do html, para inlcuir ou não os dados do $_GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque um `else` na função e monte o array padrão:

```
private function SetImageAndColor($client_id) {
    if (isset($_GET['color']) AND isset($_GET['image'])) {
        $dados['client'] [$client_id] ['image'] = $this->input->get('image');
        $dados['client'] [$client_id] ['color'] = $this->input->get('color');
    } else {
        $dados['client'][$client_id] = array(
            'image' => 'aqui vai a imagem padrao',
            'color' => 'aqui vai a cor padrao'
        );
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata('client', $dados);
}
```

E na view você simplesmente exibe, sem verificar.

Comment: Valeu mano, ajudou muito!

Answer (score 2):

Utilize isset() ele retorna true caso exista algo

Exemplo:

```
$var ="";
if(isset($_GET['suavar'])){

//Se existir o GET você atribui o valor, caso contrário, a variável fica valendo ""
$var =$_GET['suavar']
}
```

Lembrando que o $_GET[]  é uma variável do tipo array, você também pode utilizar

```
if(!empty($_GET)){
//faça algo
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde Stuney, ele deixou bem claro que ele quer verificar o `$_GET` no `View`. A questão dele é passar os dados do `Controller` para o `View`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu já consegui fazer a passagem para a view, a minha dúvida é como fazer a substituição da imagem e cor, se o $_GET existir.

Comment: @GuilhermeWermann Sim, entendi, mas a resposta aqui não está falando sobre o Controller e o View, portanto não é o problema, mesmo que você tenha conseguido "passar", ainda sim a sua questão é do Controller passar dados do `ELSE` para o View, portanto a resposta aqui não fala sobre isto. Não é uma critica negativa, só estou tentando ajudar o AP a melhorar a resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ok, obrigado!